# In R, what is the default link function used when using the glm function with binomial family

Tags: r, glm

For instance, if I have the equation

```
glm(resp~var, family=binomial)
```

Is this the same as

```
glm(resp~var, family=binomial(link=logit))
```

Or does it use a different link as default?

Comment: The default link is `logit`. Type `?family`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize I could do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the default is the logit link function. You can find out the link function of a family object using `$link`:

```
binomial()$link
# [1] "logit"
```

Answer (score 1):

- There are three common choices for link functions regarding binomial data: logit, probit and complementary log-log.
- "logit" is the default choice.
- The R code example:

  ```
  >library(faraway)
  >data(bliss)
  # using logit 
  >modl<-glm(cbind(dead,alive)~conc,family=binomial,data=bliss)
  # using probit
  >modp<-glm(cbind(dead,alive)~conc,family=binomial(link=probit),data=bliss)
  #using complementary log-log
  >modc<-glm(cbind(dead,alive)~conc,family=binomial(link=cloglog),data=bliss)
  ```